# If I have a series of points (coordinates), how do I find the location of a new point as far away from all the other points as possible?

Tags: geometry

If I have a map with a series of locations and I want to find a new point which is at the maximum distance away from all of these points but within the interior of the boundary made up of the outermost points. In layman's terms, how would i go about this?

Apologise if there is lack of clarity, I haven't done much maths for a while!

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382775/find-the-point-which-is-furthest-away-from-existing-points-while-remaining-withi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the point which is furthest away from existing points while remaining within the convex hull](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382775/find-the-point-which-is-furthest-away-from-existing-points-while-remaining-withi)